# Pandas lib gives a weird error "Length of values does not match length of index"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas python library, and I get an error which I don't understand.

"Length of values (100) does not match length of index (4)",

Whereas my params are a tuple of 100 items (rows) and a tuple of 4 strings.

Should I pack the rows differently?

[image]

Comment: What is your intention? What should your resulting dataframe look like? You can't magically create four columns out of a single array of 100 items.

Comment: I can't read your image. Please replace it with copy-pasted code. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please show a subset of your items. Just a few rows, so we get a better idea.

Comment: When you are passing `column_names` to the `pd.DataFrame()` class that is being inferred as the `index` argument, since you are not specifying that to be `column = column_names`. Please follow the previous comments to get a specific solution and read the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the `pd.DataFrame` constructor is the index not the column names.

To set the column names use the `columns` parameter:

```py
pd.DataFrame(results['rows'], columns=column_names)
```